# Shift Right Logical from an ADD and NAND?

Tags: assembly, addition, bit-shift

Asking this question a second time because last time people avoided my question and suggested solutions I could not use. I'm making a multiplier in a very simple assembly language in which I have BEQ, NAND, and ADD to create a SRL. I also have to keep the multiplier under 50 lines (16 used thus far) so hopefully the solution can be thrown in a loop.

My question is how can I implement an SRL with just a NAND and an ADD

Note: Please don't suggest multiplying by adding a number to itself x times. The method I am working on now can be completed with figuring out the SRL problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think people "avoided" your question.  This is not much to work with.  NAND operates bitwise, so the only hope you have of getting information between bit positions with an instruction is the carry in an add.  We have `x+x = SLL x`.  You didn't say anything about your processor.  If you have register pairs, you can load x in the low register of a pair and then shift left N-1 times for N bit wide registers.  The high register will have what you need.

Otherwise there is a test and set loop.

```
  ans = 0
  test = 2
  set = 1
next:
  if NAND(-1,NAND(x,test)) == 0 goto skip_set
  ans = ans + set
skip_set: 
  set = set + set
  test = test + test
  if test == 0 goto done
  goto next
done:
```

Finally if your words are narrow, you can write a table in memory.

I know you are looking for an SRL, but it's certainly possible to implement multiplication with only SLL.  For `x*y`, it would be something like:

```
  ans = 0
  test = 1
next:
  if NAND(-1,NAND(x,test)) == 0 goto skip
  ans = ans + y
skip:
  y = y + y
  test = test + test
  if test == 0 goto done
  goto next
done:
```

Comment: You too have AND instead of NAND

Comment: I assumed everyone could figure out that `NAND(1,NAND(a,b)) == AND(a, b)`!

Comment: I should have mentioned that of course for a word rather than a bit, you'd want `NAND(all ones, NAND(a,b))` or if you have twos complement arithmetic, then `NAND(-1, NAND(a,b))`.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen with only NAND or NOR you can do any boolean logic expression, and some early programmable chips do have 1 or 2 arrays of NANDs/NORs